playwright: await page.content() не работает и не выводит содержимое
Я написал парсер на playwright. С помощью на него я перехожу в определенный раздел сайта, и должен взять html-код страницы, чтобы ее распарсить и получить необходимые мне данные. Вот только код работает идеально до того момента, когда надо получать html-код страницы. Содержимое просто не выводится. Код ошибки:

playwright._impl._errors.TimeoutError: Timeout 30000ms exceeded

async with async_playwright() as playwright:
    browser = await playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    page = await browser.new_page()
    await page.goto(url)
    await page.locator("#input-1").fill('')
    await page.locator("#input-2").fill('')
    await page.get_by_role('button', name="Sign in").click()
    await page.get_by_role('button', name="Дополнить описание").click()    
    await page.wait_for_load_state()
    html = await page.content()
    print(html)


Код работате идеально. Содержимое html выводится.

После детального чтения документации и методов проб и ошибок у меня все же не получилось создать новое окно и уже работать с ним, но я просто изменил url адрес на тот, который я переходил после нажатия кнопки дополнить. Соответственно страница оставалась также, оставалось просто пройти аутентификацию
